# Facebook/Meta Alert - Permission access expired due to lack of use although it was used

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My apps is used to retrieving leads and its data associated.
On August I received alert about expired ads_management due to lack of use and app review status for this permission is 'Revoked'.  According to meta docs this permission is required, but all process still works.
Is it the disinformation in the meta docs and this permission isn't required?
If not how to restore this permission?  I can't submit for App Review, because the button is inactive with message: To request advanced access to this permission, you need to make a successful test API call...

Comment: We have the same issue. Could you find a solution ?

Comment: Not altogether. I still don't know how to ask about re-review. But I got to know that only standard access is required in my situation and I suppose that I still having it.